# JbossEAPのバグ修正がWildflyに反映されるか

Tags: jboss, wildfly

下記のリンク先には、

[JBoss EAP 7 does not process requests for a session in parallel](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2776221)

> NOTE : However there are bugs that prevent this configuration from working, that are scheduled to be fixed in EAP 7.0.4 (JBEAP-6752) and 7.1 (JBEAP-4128).

と書かれています。
このバグが、Wildflyではどのバージョンから修正されているのか知りたいです。
具体的なバージョン、または調べる方法をご存知の方いませんか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

そちらのページのリンクから辿れますが、[JBEAP-6752](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-6752)は[JBEAP-4128](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-4128)のバックーポート対応、JBEAP-4128自身はIssue Linksにある通り[WFLY-6502](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-6502)のcloneなので、WildFlyで対応されているのは(Issue Trackerに書かれていることを信じるなら)`10.1.0.CR1`以降ではないでしょうか。